# Prove $\lim_{x\to a }{ f(x)\over g(x)}={ L\over M}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

Suppose lim x→a f(x) = L and lim x→a g(x) = M, prove that

lim x→a [f(x)/g(x)]= L/M provided M ≠ 0 and g(x) ≠ 0, for x suﬃciently close to a (but not equal to a).

What does mean by for x suﬃciently close to a (but not equal to a) and how can I prove that?

thanks

Comment: The condition "and $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ (but not equal to $a$)" is redundant. It is implied by $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = M \neq 0$.

Comment: Quesiton: Can you prove $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\cdot g(x)=LM$? Can you do that with an $\varepsilon,\delta$ proof?